# DB2 merge via jdbc, performance and operation type

Tags: jdbc, db2

I'm issuing a db2 merge statement as prepared statement via jdbc and I would like to check whether anybody knows something about...

1. performance? is it really better than..

   - an update and in case of error an insert
   - or a retrieve and then the proper operation (insert or update according to the retrieve result)
2. is there any method, via jdbc api, to understand besides the number of affected row, what kind of operation (insert or update) has been performed?

thanks in advance
Fil

Answer (score 1):

We have an application that we use the `MERGE` for.  Basically, we read a large amount of inputs, calculate values using these, and insert the resulting calculated values into the database (whose "keys" may or may not already exist).

Our application is .NET, so we're not using JDBC, but here are some general notes from our tests:

When using `MERGE` as opposed to "delete everything then re-insert", at the worst, the `MERGE` would at least match the performance of the `INSERT` method.

Most improvements in initial inserting/updaing were usually small, but using the `MERGE` had the side-effect of not requiring a `RUNSTATS` or a `REORG` as often, and this saved us quite a lot of processing power, and improved general performance of the application.

Additionally, the `MERGE` method was much more consistent than the `DELETE`/`INSERT` method.  The old method would vary anywhere between 5-10 seconds for a very small calculation, where the `MERGE` would only vary in the range of a second or two.

Hope that helps a little!